# Excel 2013: Show slicers based on a certan selection on a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot

Is it possible to display a slicer based on a certain selection on a field in a pivot table?

I have a large number of fields into a two-layer hierarchy, let's say I have level 1 hierarchy with the values `A`, `B`, `C` (YES/NO option only) and a second level with the fields `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, etc. I have built the pivot table adding the filters `A, B` and `C`. If I add the second level the number of fields displayed on the pivot will be too large, so I'd like to display slicers based on a selection. For example, if the value in field `A` is `YEE`, then display the slicers for `A1`, `A2` and `A3`.

Is this possible?